# Si tengo 20 imagenes que mostrar en cuadros de dialogo... ¿tengo qué crear 20 layouts?

Tags: java, android, layout, alertdialog

Tengo 20 botones, al darle clic a cada botón se muestra un cuadro de dialogo con una imagen; cree un layout por cada imagen (20 imagenes, 20 layout).

Quisiera saber si es posible crear un solo layout con todas las imágenes, porque intente hacerlo con un solo layout pero, me marca un error.

.xml (**SOLO PONGO DOS IMAGEVIEW PARA NO HACER TAN LARGO EL TEXTO AQUI**)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/img1"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/img2"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

botones.java

```
@Override

    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnImg1:
                LayoutInflater imagen = LayoutInflater.from(Botones.this);
                final View vista = imagen.inflate(R.id.img1, null);

                AlertDialog.Builder alerta = new AlertDialog.Builder(Botones.this);
                alerta.setCancelable(true);
                dialog = alerta.create();
                dialog.setView(vista);
                dialog.show();
                break;
           }
}
```

El error que me marca es el siguiente:

**android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0800fe type #0x12 is not valid**

Comment: Veo tu código y el método onClick() no esta siendo llamado desde el layout. Lees btnImg1 pero en el layout no esta este elemento

Comment: Ese layout solo es para las imágenes, los botones están en otro layout, pero el error que marca es aquí: R.id.img1. cuando mando llamar el id de la imagen. Pero si lo hago por separado, cada imagen en un layout y mando llamar el layout en lugar de la imagen R.layout.imagenes si me muestra la imagen. @Elenasys♦

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando llamas al método `inflate` espera recibir un layout (`R.layout.my_layout`) y no un ID (`R.id.img1`).

Lo que tienes que hacer es crear un layout con solamente un ImageView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Para mostrar una imagen diferente según el botón que presiones haces lo siguiente.

Primero creas una referencia hacia el ImageView:

```
ImageView image = findViewById(R.id.img)
```

Luego usando la referencia puedes cambiar la imagen según el botón:

Botón 1:

```
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagen1)
```

Botón 2:

```
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagen2)
```

Botón n:

```
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagenN)
```

Comment: Gracias por responder @Glenn Sandoval, realicé lo que indicas y me sale la siguiente excepción java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @kayvos Revisa la línea donde te da el error porque estás usando una referencia que está en `null`.

Comment: Así es, leí que esa excepción es porque llamo a alago nulo pero, la línea donde marca esa excepción es en esta, image.setImageResource(R.drawable.vaso). La imagen (vaso) si la tengo en drawable y la variable img es el id del ImageView que tengo en el layout. @Glenn Sandoval

Comment: @kayvos La variable `image` está en `null`. Revisa que esté inicializada, o sea revisa que se le asignó lo que devuelve `findViewById` antes de ejecutar la línea donde te lanza el error.

Comment: La estaba inicializando mal, muchas gracias @Glenn Sandoval :D eres un genio. Ya acepté tu respuesta ;)